# SQL query to search last conversation between users

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure database of message exchange

```
DB - User
id_user - name - last_name
1          A       A
2          B       B
3          C       C
4          D       D
5          E       E
```

DB Message -conversations are saved in the following structure

```
id - from - to -  message - date
1     1     2    msg(here)  (date here)
2     2     1      
3     1     2 
4     4     1
5     4     1
6     1     5
```

the help I need is to make a sql query to return me the last idependete conversation if sent or received 
exmeplo the results you need to get the conversation User 1

```
id - from - to ...
 3     1      2   
 5     4      1
 6     1      5
```

ie seek independent last message sent or received if not repeat the pro order others and get the name and surname in the users table to display on the screen

end result on screen

```
 mensagens
 name last_name  mensagem
  b      b        mensagem
  d      d        mensagem
  e      e        mensagem



SELECT distinct * FROM menssage inner join user on from = id_user where to LIKE '$session' 
union SELECT distinct * FROM message inner join user on to = id_user where from LIKE '$session' 
group by id_user  order by  id asc
```

Comment: What have you tried? We need to see some non-working code before we can help fix it...

Comment: SELECT distinct * FROM menssage inner join user on from = id_user where to LIKE '$session' 
union SELECT distinct * FROM message inner join user on to = id_user where from LIKE '$session' 
group by id_user  order by  id asc

Answer (score 0):

Logic is simple: You create a data set as UserID (Having both from & to in it), date & message. so that you have data for all sent & received messages in single data set. 
- Now life is quite easy, just rank it by date time & chose latest 1 message for that user & show it with its name, Lname & message :)

Sample code for PostgreSQL.

```
    create table DBuser (userid int, name char(10), last_name char(20));
    insert into DBuser values(1, 'A', 'LA');
    insert into DBuser values(2, 'B', 'LB');
    insert into DBuser values(3, 'C', 'LC');
    insert into DBuser values(4, 'D', 'LD');
    insert into DBuser values(5, 'E', 'LE');
    select * from DBUser


    create table DBMessages (id int, Ufrom int, Uto int, message text, Mdate time);
    insert into DBMessages values (1, 1, 2, 'Hello 1', CURRENT_time);
    insert into DBMessages values (2, 2, 1, 'Hello 2', CURRENT_time);
    insert into DBMessages values (3, 1, 2, 'Hello 3', CURRENT_time);
    insert into DBMessages values (4, 4, 1, 'Hello 4', CURRENT_time);
    insert into DBMessages values (5, 4, 1, 'Hello 5', CURRENT_time);
    insert into DBMessages values (6, 1, 5, 'Hello 6', CURRENT_time);

    select * from DBMessages;

    select name, 
           last_name, 
           message 
      from DBuser, 
    (select userID, 
            message, 
            rank() over (PARTITION BY userID order by Mdate desc) as rank 
       from (select Ufrom as userID, 
                    message,
                    Mdate
               from DBMessages
               union all
             select Uto as userID, 
                    message,
                    Mdate
               from DBMessages
           )  as data 
    ) as rankeddata 
   where rank =1 
   and rankeddata.userID = DBUser.userid;

Name    Last_Name   Message
"A"     "LA"        "Hello 6"
"B"     "LB"        "Hello 3"
"D"     "LD"        "Hello 5"
"E"     "LE"        "Hello 6"
```